# Windows phone 7 live tiles and push notification

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, live-tile, mpns

i need help. I have done push notification for my app. I want the tile to change to the image that the push notification sends. How do i do this. All this is to be done in one app itself. The examples that i saw in msdn and other websites show some secondary  image which i dont get plus they require two app. I dont understand how it works. Please help. I want the live tile to display the image that the push notification has sent. Sample codes would be appreaciated. Please and Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the Code Samples provided on the following site, these include sample code in both C# and VB.NET and cover various aspects of Windows Phone development, included Live Tiles :-

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/

Comment: Uri now returns a 404